# Creating WCF service with xml

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, service

I need to create WCF service , but instead of function definition I have 2 XML files 
one for answer, second for response. How to use that xml file to define function in my service?

Comment: What do you want to do with this XML files? Read and include in response?

Comment: is it normal to include xml file to rsponse?

Comment: It depends on what client of your sevice do with this xml